# Pi-Hole: How to change DNS via command

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, pi-hole

I use Pi-Hole on my Raspberry Pi 2. It's very easy to change the Pi-Hole DNS using the *Web Interface Settings*.

**But how can I change my Pi-Hole DNS via command in my raspberry pi console? (Raspbian)**

I am looking for something like this:

`root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# pihole` **`changedns`** `my.new.dns.server`

Answer (score 2):

I understand that Pi-hole uses `dnsmasq` to implement blacklisting, so the first thing I'd try is to edit `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and reload the configuration with either

```
killall -s SIGHUP dnsmasq
```

or

```
service dnsmasq restart
```

If that works, you should find a way to edit the config file from a script. This is typically done with `sed` or `awk`. Something like:

```
sudo sed "s/server=.*/server=my.new.dns.server/g" /etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instruction:

1.Add the DNS server to host:

```
sudo echo "nameserver my.new.dns.server" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
```

2.Add the new DNS server to the dnsmasq config file:

```
sudo sed "s/server=.*/server=my.new.dns.server/g" /etc/dnsmasq.confq
```

3.Restart dnsmasq service:

```
sudo systemctl reload dnsmasq
```

or test this one:

```
sudo service dnsmasq restart
```

You can also use this little command to it:

```
sudo echo "nameserver my.new.dns.server" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf && sudo sed "s/server=.*/server=my.new.dns.server/g" /etc/dnsmasq.confq  && sudo systemctl reload dnsmasq
```

There is also another way which **pihole** clients DNS is your host and you just need to change the hosts DNS server.
For example (the host ip is 192.168.1.100):

```
sudo sed "s/server=.*/server=192.168.1.100/g" /etc/dnsmasq.confq
```

Then

```
sudo echo "nameserver my.new.dns.server" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
```